# PHP redirect based on computer machine

Tags: php, redirect

IS there a way in PHP to recognize the user machine and do a redirection to a different page if the Computer is not allowed to visit the website?

I need it for making a coming_soon page.

I want to allow people who I know and nobody else, and I would like to avoid IP redirection, because our IPs change constantly.

Please let me know

Thanks

Comment: IP address is the only way. There is no other way to uniquely identify a machine on the interwebz. (Disclaimer: there is MAC address, but I'm not sure how you would access that in PHP, how you would know, based on MAC address, who's who, and finally MAC address is easily changeable)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is pretty much a solid "no".
The only way to really identify someone is via a MAC address, (and even this can be spoofed) , but MAC addresses are not available on the Internet layer of the OSI model, thus you are stuck with identification by IP.

One option would be to run some kind of a Java applet that would take a look at the MAC and record it, but the user would have to give permission for this, and quite frankly this is not worth the effort.

In conclusion I would say that given your scenario, it would make a lot more sense to include a special URL parameter that would be given to the people that need to see the page as it really is. So, in your case (if security is not a problem), obfuscation via a special URL is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can recognize the user by doing proper **authentication** of course.

Apart  from that, there is no trival way to do this...

The only condition  you can ever identify them is if they would some kind of proxy server, and proxy's IP are usually fixed. But again, this is by no mean "authentication" or even reliable.

Answer (score 0):

As Uku Loskit already said.

But, you can create a hidden `$_GET`. Something like `example.org/?setSecretCookie`. If someone visits this page, he receives a cookie and only people with this cookie are allowed to view the real page, instead of the coming soon landing page.